# R: Suggestion to speed up a function (remove duplicates in data frame)

Tags: r, dplyr

I run into a bit of trouble with my code and would welcome any suggestion to make it run faster.
I have a data frame that looks like that:

```
Name <- c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c")

Category <- c("sun","cat","sun","sun","sea","sun","sea","cat","dog","cat")

More_info <- c("table","table","table","table","table","table","table","table","table","cat")
d <- data.frame(Name,Category,More_info)
```

So I have duplicated entries for each row in column Name (the number of duplicates can vary). For each entry (a,b,...) I want to count the sum of each corresponding element in the Category column and keep the only category that appears the most. If an entry has an equal number of categories, I want to take one of most categories randomly.
So in this case, the output dataframe would look like this:

```
Name <- c("a","b","c")

Category <- c("sun","dog","cat")

More_info <- c("table","table","table")
d <- data.frame(Name,Category,More_info)
```

a have sun entry kept because it appears the most, b would be dog or whatever other value as they all appear once with b, and c wouldn't be changed.
My function looks like this:

```
    my_choosing_function <- function(x){
      tmp = dbSNP_hapmap[dbSNP_hapmap$refsnp_id==list_of_snps[x],]
      snp_freq <- as.data.frame(table(tmp$consequence_type_tv)) 
       best_hit <- snp_freq[order(-snp_freq$Freq),]
      best_hit$SNP<-list_of_snps[x]
      top<-best_hit[1,]
      return(top)
    }
    trst <- lapply(1:length(list_of_snps), function(x) my_choosing_function(x))
final <- do.call("rbind",trst)
```

Where I start from a list of unique elements (that would be Name in our case), for each element I do a table of the duplicated entries, I order the table by descending values and keep the top element. I do a lapply for each element of the list of unique values, then do a rbind of the whole thing.

As I have 2500000 rows in my initial data frame and 1500000 unique elements, it takes forever to run. 4 seconds for 100 lines, that would be a total of 34 hours for the lapply.

I'm sure packages like dplyr can do it in a few minutes but can't find a solution to do it. Anyone has an idea?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

#### Note: This should be a very long comment because I use `data.table` instead of `dplyr`.

I suggest use `data.table` because it runs faster. And in the `data.table` way shown below, it **randomly** choose one in case of tie, not always the first one.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

d <- data.frame(
    Name = as.character(sample.int(10000, 2.5e6, replace = T)),
    Category = as.character(sample.int(10000, 2.5e6, replace = T)),
    More_info = rep('table', 2.5e6)
)

Mode <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    fr1 <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
    if(n_distinct(fr1)==1) ux[sample(seq_along(fr1), 1)] else ux[which.max(fr1)]
}

system.time({
    d %>%
        group_by(Name) %>%
        slice(which(Category == Mode(Category))[1])
})
#    user  system elapsed
#  45.932   0.808  46.745

system.time({
    dt <- as.data.table(d)
    dt.max <- dt[, .N, by = .(Name, Category)]
    dt.max[, r := frank(-N, ties.method = 'random'), by = .(Name)]
    dt.max <- dt.max[r == 1, .(Name, Category)]

    dt[dt.max, on = .(Name, Category), mult = 'first']
})
#    user  system elapsed
#   2.424   0.004   2.426
```

Comment: This solution was insanely fast, I processed the whole 2.5M lines in under 4 minutes instead of 40h for my initial function! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We can modify the `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode) and then do a group by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x)
 fr1 <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  if(n_distinct(fr1)==1) ux[sample(seq_along(fr1), 1)] else ux[which.max(fr1)]
}

d %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  slice(which(Category == Mode(Category))[1])
```

Comment: Does this run faster than the one from OP? I think some benchmarks would be helpful.

Comment: @mt1022 I haven't checked the benchmarks, but `tabulate` is faster than `table` and the OP specified for `dplyr` solutions.  I think the OP will compare the speed as he already have a big dataset

Comment: Also it seems that the OP's function does not work on the example data.

Comment: @mt1022  It is not clear about the `list_of_snps` i.e. `trst <- lapply(1:length(list_of_snps), function(x) my_choosing_function(x))#
Error in lapply(1:length(list_of_snps), function(x) my_choosing_function(x)) : 
  object 'list_of_snps' not found`

Comment: Yes, I create a list of characters from the unique elements in the column first (I didn't mention it, my code was to show how I was doing overall).

Thanks a lot akrun and mt1022 for your replies, I will system time all that and will let you know which one is faster! I really like both of your examples though, they are very clever!

Answer (score 0):

A couple slight tweaks on @mt1022's solution can produce a *marginal* speedup, nothing to phone home about, but might be of use if you find your data grows another order of magnitude.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(
 Name = as.character(sample.int(10000, 2.5e6, replace = T)),
 Category = as.character(sample.int(5000, 2.5e6, replace = T)),
 More_info = rep('table', 2.5e6)
)

Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x)
 fr1 <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
 if(n_distinct(fr1)==1) ux[sample(seq_along(fr1), 1)] else ux[which.max(fr1)]
}

system.time({
 d %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   slice(which(Category == Mode(Category))[1])
})

# user   system elapsed 
# 40.459   0.180  40.743 

system.time({
 dt <- as.data.table(d)
 dt.max <- dt[, .N, by = .(Name, Category)]
 dt.max[, r := frank(-N, ties.method = 'random'), by = .(Name)]
 dt.max <- dt.max[r == 1, .(Name, Category)]

 dt[dt.max, on = .(Name, Category), mult = 'first']
})

# user  system elapsed 
# 4.196   0.052   4.267
```

Tweaks include

- Use `setDT()` instead of `as.data.table()` to avoid making a copy
- Using `stats::runif()` to generate the random tiebreaker directly, this is of what `data.table` is doing internally in the the random option of `frank()`
- Using `setkey()` to sort the table
- Sub-setting the table by the row indices, `.I`, where the row within each group is equal to the number of observations, `.N` in each group. *(This returns the last row of each group)*

Results:

```
system.time({
 dt.max <- setDT(d)[, .(Count = .N), keyby = .(Name, Category)]
 dt.max[,rand := stats::runif(.N)]
 setkey(dt.max,Name,Count, rand)
 dt.max[dt.max[,.I[.N],by = .(Name,Category)]$V1,.(Name,Category,Count)]
})

# user  system elapsed 
# 1.722   0.057   1.750
```